# Why am I getting a carbon instance from a model attribute?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, php-carbon

I have this collection of riv_queries.

```
$riv_queries = RivQuery::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

```
RivQuery {#157 ▼

#attributes: array:12 [▼
    "id" => 88
    "riv_from" => "2019-10-15"
    "riv_to" => "2019-10-15"
    "department_id" => 109
    "type_id" => 0
    "record_type_id" => 1
    "cal_year" => 2018
    "accordion" => 0
    "city_id" => 0
    "region_id" => 8
    "prov_id" => 837
    "tx_date" => "2019-10-15"
  ]
```

> My problem is whenever I want to get 'riv_to' or 'riv_from' I always get this as a result

```
dd($riv_queries->riv_to);
```

```
Carbon @1571068800 {#638 ▼
  date: 2019-10-15 00:00:00.0 Asia/Manila (+08:00)
}
```

> But i only expect result like this

```
"2019-10-15"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any fields defined in `$dates` property is converted to `Carbon` automatically: [Date Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators).

> By default, Eloquent will convert the created_at and updated_at
>   columns to instances of Carbon, which extends the PHP DateTime class
>   and provides an assortment of helpful methods. You may add additional
>   date attributes by setting the $dates property of your model

You can also format the `Carbon` instance to `string` like:

```
$riv_queries->riv_to->format('Y-M-d');
```

Comment: but riv_from and riv_to is not a timestamp in my database why is it so?

Comment: @Franz So what is your `riv_from` type? Show your `RivQuery` please. Maybe there is something we can dig into.

Comment: riv_from and riv_to types is date

Comment: @Franz Did you define `$dates` field in the model? Eloquent also converts any fields in `$dates` property to `Carbon`. [See more](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: Yes, its now clear thanks a lot. i'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

dd((string)$riv_queries->riv_to);

Comment: it returns "2019-10-15 00:00:00" but i only want "2019-10-15"

Comment: Carbon::parse($riv_queries->riv_to)->format('Y-m-d');